# Android studio is not showing the line number of error in logcat

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, logcat

I am trying to get firebase realtime database data into the **ViewHolder** class but the app is crashing and logcat is not specifying the line in which the error is occurring. Below is the logcat
**Logcat**

```
2022-01-26 22:04:46.007 10834-11362/com.xee.fiverrimpressions E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #6
    Process: com.xee.fiverrimpressions, PID: 10834
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:415)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.startsWith(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.nguyencse.URLEmbeddedTask.doInBackground(URLEmbeddedTask.java:26)
        at com.nguyencse.URLEmbeddedTask.doInBackground(URLEmbeddedTask.java:13)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
2022-01-26 22:04:46.097 10834-10834/com.xee.fiverrimpressions I/ViewRootImpl@9fa7fd8[DashboardActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
2022-01-26 22:04:46.108 10834-11362/com.xee.fiverrimpressions I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10834 SIG: 9
```

**MyViewHolder**

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView geglink, userName, userAbout;
    URLEmbeddedView previewLink;
    View v;
    DatabaseReference dRef;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    String UID;

    String fiverrLink1;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        previewLink =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.uev);
        geglink = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rcvGigLink);
        userName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rcvName);
        userAbout = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rcvAbout);
        v = itemView;

        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        dRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

        if(fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
            UID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

        }

     dRef.child(UID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
             fiverrLink1 = (String) snapshot.child("gig").getValue();
         }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

         }
     });

        previewLink.setURL(fiverrLink1, new URLEmbeddedView.OnLoadURLListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadURLCompleted(URLEmbeddedData data) {
                previewLink.title(data.getTitle());
                previewLink.description(data.getDescription());
                previewLink.host(data.getHost());
                previewLink.thumbnail(data.getThumbnailURL());
                previewLink.favor(data.getFavorURL());
            }
        });
```

I think the error is in  **addValueEventListener** as if I write **fiverrLink1 = "https://www.youtube.com"** outside addValueEventListener the app works perfectly. Please help what is causing the error and how to solve it. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crashed happened here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.startsWith(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.nguyencse.URLEmbeddedTask.doInBackground(URLEmbeddedTask.java:26)
        at com.nguyencse.URLEmbeddedTask.doInBackground(URLEmbeddedTask.java:13)
```

File: URLEmbeddedTask.java line #26

You called `startsWith()` on a null string and the background task crashed

You can for example add some log messages and add a null check:

```
if(tempString != null) {
    System.out.println("String is not null.. OK scenario")
    tempString.startsWith(/*aaaa*/);
} else {
    System.out.println("String is null.. NOK scenario")
}
```

**Update**

I found the class that you are using on [GitHub](https://github.com/nguyencse/URLEmbeddedView/blob/master/urlembeddedview/src/main/java/com/nguyencse/URLEmbeddedTask.java):

As you can see, on line #26, the `url` is used without checking if it is null or not:

```
String url = params[0];
url = ((url.startsWith(URLConstants.PROTOCOL) || url.startsWith(URLConstants.PROTOCOL_S)) ? "" : URLConstants.PROTOCOL) + url;
```

So, this issue is happening because you are calling the `task.execute();` with a null parameter.

```
URLEmbeddedTask task = new URLEmbeddedTask(/*listerner*/);
task.execute(/* THIS OBJECT CAN BE NULL */);
```

**UPDATE #2**

I debug that library and I found that this is the error:

```
String fiverrLink1;

dRef.child(UID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        fiverrLink1 = (String) snapshot.child("gig").getValue();
        // Only here filverrLink1 wont be null. Only after this callback is invoked.
    }
});

// Here, fiverrLink1 is null. It will be non-null only after the onDataChanged call back is invoked.
previewLink.setURL(fiverrLink1 ... ); // -> You are sending null to the library
```

**How to Fix**

Well, this depends of what you want to achive. But I would suggest to invoke `setUrl` only after `fiverrLink1` is updated. Something like:

```
String fiverrLink1;

dRef.child(UID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        fiverrLink1 = (String) snapshot.child("gig").getValue();
        previewLink.setURL(fiverrLink1 ... ); // -> Move to here
    }
});
```

Comment: The same code is working perfectly when I try to get the value .child("gig") in main activity

Comment: MyViewHolder is not an activity. Is it possible that the problem is occuring due to this?

Comment: There's no error in your activity or view model. Error is happening on file URLEmbeddedTask because you are using a String without properly ensuring that strings isn't null

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: Okay I'll try the solution.

Comment: I updated the asnwer with a better explanation of the root cause and a possible solution. However, it's not possible to give you a better and refined solution because it depends of what to want to achieve. At least, I believe I answered why you're getting a NPE (null pointer exception)

Comment: Problem solved.